# Rounding float to int

Tags: c, rounding

Self studying coding (noob here), the answer to a practice problem is as follows:

`amount = (int) round (c);`

Where `c` is a float.
Is it safe to say that this line converts the float to an integer through rounding? 
I tried researching methods of converting floats to integers but none used the syntax as above.

Comment: At the moment I've only made it to 'C', but will look into those on Java. Thanks.

Comment: @COBB87 you should mention the language you're writing that code in

Comment: @Popeye you shouldn't be assuming that Java is the only programming language someone will write code in.

Comment: Note: Also look into using `long lroundf(float x);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look at the return value of `round`.
If it returns a float, then your `int` casting will not lose precision and will convert the float to an `int`.
If it returns an `int`, then the conversion happens in the function, and there is no need to try converting it again.

This is of course if you really wish to round the number. If you want `10.8` to become `11`, then your code is a possible solution, but if you want it to become `10`, then just convert (cast) it to an `int`.

Comment: Casting a 32-bit `float` to a 32-bit `int` _does_ lose precision for many values greater than about 2**23.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do `amount = int(c)`

Here is a full example

```
amount = 10.3495829
amount = int(amount)
print(amount)
```

It should print 10!

Comment: This truncates 9.99 to 9, not rounds to 10.

Answer (score 0):

float has the higher range than integer primitive value, which means a float is a bigger than int. Due to this fact you can convert a float to an int by just down-casting it

```
int value = (int) 9.99f; // Will return 9
```

Just note, that this typecasting will truncate everything after the decimal point , it won't perform any rounding or flooring operation on the value. 
As you see from above example if you have float of 9.999, (down) casting to an integer will return 9 . However If you need rounding then use `Math.round()` method, which converts float to its nearest integer by adding +0.5 to it's value and then truncating it.

[Java tutorial , primitive datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

[Java language specifications, casting of primitive types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html)

Comment: umm.. the question is tagged `C`